# Quarkus upgrade, hibernate schemavalidation fails

Tags: quarkus

I'm getting the following error:

`13:30:44 ERROR [io.qua.hib.orm.run.sch.SchemaManagementIntegrator] (Hibernate post-boot validation thread for <default>) Failed to validate Schema: Schema-validation: missing table [DispatchTransactionMetricEntity]`

The message is correct. There is no table `DispatchTransactionMetricEntity`.

My entity is just a `@SqlResultSetMapping` collecting results from several other tables. The added annotation `@Entity` is  mandatory for this to work. However, it seems to trigger some kind of validation causing errors in the log to appear.

So: is there a way to fix this?

**Update:** In the mean time I found the setting: 'quarkus.hibernate-orm.validate-in-dev-mode=false'. That seems to avoid the error message. But it still raises the question whether its right to assume that each `@Entity` is also an `@Table`..